# Simple Chessboard in java

Tags: java

I want to make a simple chess board in java. The input is integer n and the output must be n×n Chessboard. `*` represents black field and  (space) represents white field. For Example, for n=5 the Chess board would be like this:

```
* * *
 * * 
* * *
 * * 
* * *
```

so far i already wrote the code like this but it has no white field just black field (`*`).

[image: code]

Comment: Just copy your code into your question. No need to use external pictures for showing your code.

Comment: Please take a moment and read tag descriptions before you add them. This is not a question about design patterns nor chessboard.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to make your black and white fields dependent of both of your for-loop counters.

```
for(int i =0; i < n; i++) 
{
  for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
  {
    if( (i+j) % 2 == 0){
      System.out.print("*");
    }
    else {
      System.out.print(" ");  
    }
  }
  System.out.println("");
}
```

or switch the `" "` and `"*"` to let your chessboard start with a white field in the upper left corner.

Comment: I'm happy I could help.

Feel free to upvote answers or mark one of them as "the answer that helped solving my problem" after a reasonably amount of time.