# Is there an easier way to add the black/white squares for my checkers game in Java then what I'm already using?

Tags: java, math

Basically the title. I'm creating a checkers game and there needs to be two sets of empty squares - black and white. As of now I'm just entering the location of each square manually (each square that needs to be black rather than white), but this is quite long when it's an 8x8 board... Is there any easier way? I tried some sort of mathematical formula but it's annoying because the black square goes every other square, up until the fourth square when it doesn't skip, e.g. the black square would be every 0th - 2nd - 4th - 6th and then 9th square, and then 9 - 11 - 13 - 15 - 16 etc. (just look at a checkers board if I didn't explain this properly). I could just add the possible locations to a array to make it easier, but that still doesn't really seem like a good idea.

I'm doing this in Java, it basically looks like this right now:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        if (i == 0 || i == 2 || i == 4 || i == 6 || i == 9 || i == 11 || i == 13 || i == 15 || i == 16 || i == 18 || i == 20 || i == 22) {
            s = new Square("EMPTY-TWO", i);
        }
        else {
            s = new Square("EMPTY-ONE", i);
        }
```

Which obviously isn't ideal

Comment: Please post the code which you have already tried and tell us where you are stuck

Comment: Use some nice loops.

Comment: Updated to show the code I'm using atm. Not quite sure how to loop this so that it works as intended, hence why I'm asking...

Comment: try using if (i % 2 == 0)

Comment: I've tried that, but that doesn't work because that just goes up in multiples of two which isn't what I want, since a checkers board will go every 0 - 2 - 4 - 8 - 9, just look at a board to see what I mean.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple Chessboard in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33517247/simple-chessboard-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

In one loop but providing row and column information which you may need to display the squares:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) 
{
    int row = i / 8;
    int col = i % 8;
    boolean isBlack = ((row + col) % 2 == 0);
    System.out.println("row = " + row + ", col = " + col + ": " + (isBlack ? "black" : "white"));
}
```

With a more visible output:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
{
    int row = i / 8;
    int col = i % 8;
    boolean isBlack = ((row + col) % 2 == 0);
    if(col==0)
    {
        System.out.println("\n+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+");
        System.out.print("| ");
    }
    System.out.print((isBlack?"black":"white")+" | ");      
}
System.out.println("\n+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+");
```

This results in:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| black | white | black | white | black | white | black | white | 
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| white | black | white | black | white | black | white | black | 
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| black | white | black | white | black | white | black | white | 
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| white | black | white | black | white | black | white | black | 
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| black | white | black | white | black | white | black | white | 
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| white | black | white | black | white | black | white | black | 
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| black | white | black | white | black | white | black | white | 
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| white | black | white | black | white | black | white | black | 
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Its probably the best to explain the remainder operator, not everyone knows what it exactly does

Answer (score 0):

Try using nested for loops:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            if ((i % 2 == 0 && j % 2 == 0) || (i % 2 != 0 && j % 2 != 0)) {
                // your code here the value you had for i will now be (i * 8 + j)
            }
        }
    }
```